# Acceder a los valores de un Array que adquirió (a los valores) dentro de un bucle for en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, class

Tengo un Array llamado `userArray` y este se inicializa afuera de un bucle, pero adquiere los valores dentro de un bucle `for`. Cada vez que se ingresa un Usuario, se muestra en pantalla uno por uno, pero cuando quiero acceder al array con un alert que está por fuera del bucle `for`, me devuelve como valor [object]. Cabe destacar que incluí una clase y un objeto para que accediera al array. Les comparto mi código:

```js
class Usuario {
constructor(nombre, apellido, telefono, email) {
        this.nombre = nombre.toLowerCase();
        this.apellido = apellido.toLowerCase();
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.email = email;

    }
    verificacion() {
        while ((!this.email.includes("@")) && (!this.email.includes(".com"))) {
            alert("Su email es inválido");
            this.email = prompt("Ingrese nuevamente su email");
        }

    }
    getDatos() {
        alert("Sus datos finales ingresados son: " + this.nombre + "\n" + this.apellido + "\n" + this.telefono + "\n" + this.email);
    }
}
alert("Le pediremos que ingrese sus datos");

const userArray = [];
let quantity = 1;
for (let index = 0; index <= quantity; index++) {
    userArray[index] = new Usuario(
        prompt("Ingrese su nombre"),
        prompt("Ingrese su apellido"),
        prompt("Ingrese su teléfono"),
        prompt("Ingrese su Email")
    );
    userArray[index].verificacion();
    userArray[index].getDatos();

}
alert("Los usuarios totales que se han registrado son: "+userArray.join("\n"));
```

Una solución se me ocurrió es usar setters y getters, pero no sé cómo implementarlos.

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando intentas mostrar datos como texto, Javascript intenta usar el método `Object.toString()`. Por defecto, este método devuelve ese valor que estás viendo:

```js
let array =[
  {clave: 'valor1'},
  {clave: 'valor2'}
];
// el método toString() Array muestra los distintos elementos separados por comas
alert(array);
```

Por tanto, añadiendo un método `toString` a tu clase, puedes mostrar los valores:

```js
class Usuario {
  constructor(nombre, apellido, telefono, email) {
    this.nombre = nombre.toLowerCase();
    this.apellido = apellido.toLowerCase();
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.email = email;

  }
 // otros métodos...

  toString() {
    return this.nombre+" "+this.apellido+", Tlf:"+this.telefono+", email: " + this.email + "\n";
  }
}

const users = [
  new Usuario("juan","lópez","123123123","mail@null.com"),
  new Usuario("josé","garcía","321321321","mail2@null.com")
]

alert(users)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta. Saludos!